# Bluetooth Chat App answering back same text I sent

Tags: android, bluetooth, obd-ii

Im using one app to send data to the elm327 through bluetooth and I'm trying the AT Z command but everything I get back from the OBD2 is AT Z too, my code is missing something or its supposed to answer like that ? I expected the AT Z to return elm327 text (tested with playstore apps and thats what I got)

```
  // runs during a connection with a remote device
  private class ReadWriteThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;

    public ReadWriteThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        this.bluetoothSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        inputStream = tmpIn;
        outputStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1,
                        buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                ChatController.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // write to OutputStream
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            outputStream.write(buffer);
            handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1,
                    buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're not reading enough – make sure you concatenate all fragments you read until you receive the actual prompt `\r>`.

ELM327 usually starts out in *echo mode*, where it echos every command you are giving to it, that may explain why you're reading it back. Use `ATE0` to turn off this behavior.

In general, https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Widgets/ELM327_AT_Commands.pdf explains all that.